# php.ini sendmail_from required for Test Mail Server and Papercut?

Tags: php, apache, email

I have Windows 10 with XAMPP installed. I wanted to see what my options are for ways to test sending emails with the PHP mail() function offline for development and testing purposes. I found three ways on Windows to do this and they are...

XAMPP + Test Mail Server Tool
XAMPP + Papercut
XAMPP configured with mailtodesk

I tried out two different PHP scripts. One is a simple PHP mail() script

```
mail('me@mail.com', 'MySubject', 'Message 123...');

?>
```

And the other is a more advanced use of PHP mail() and making a HTML email.

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

For some reason I need to remove the semi-colon from the sendmail_from line in the php.ini in order for the first PHP script to work with Test Mail Server Tool and Papercut. If I do not remove the semi-colon I get the following error.

`Warning: mail(): Bad Message Returns Path in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtestbasic.php on line 3`

Why is this? When I setup mailtodisk within XAMPP I do not get this error nor do I get this error with the second PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is kinda funny as it contains a typo (return path, not returnS path)...

You need a valid `return-path` when sending your email. If `sendmail_from` is not uncommented in `php.ini`, it defaults to the Apache user @ server name, so probably something like `apache@localhost` in your dev environment, which would be refused by any SMTP.

So, setting it to a valid hostname in `php.ini` is crucial (the user part doesn't really matter but it will generate traffic on the postmaster email if neither the recipient or the return-path are valid).

You can also set it via the `additional_parameters` parameter of `mail()`, see example #4 in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

PS: `sendmail_from` might be confusing if you're not familiar with email headers It actually generates the `return-path` header that will be uses in case the email bounces. Bounced emails will not go to `From` you define in your own headers, as this is only used to display the sender (and used when replying to the email, unless you also define a `reply-to` header that might be different from the `From` one.

Comment: Yeah I typed the error message out, I didnt copy and pasted it

Comment: I tried changing sendmail_from to me@localhost and removed the semi-colon and both PHP scripts work. By a valid name does it need a TLD at the end of the name like .com, .net, .org?

Comment: Well, it depends on the final recipient. If the emails need to go outside of your local network, I would definitely use a valid email there.